# How to pass current scope to a function reference?

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6, readability

I have the following code that constructs a string and adds an event to a button that shows said string :

```
function initEvents() {
  const message = processSomeString();
  myButton.addEventListener( () => {
    //Some other code
    alert(message);
  })
}
```

The above works because in memory the anynomous event function is stored along with its outer scope.

I would like to remove the nested anonymous function to improve readability, but then how do I attach the `message` variable to referenced function?

Preferably in a modern way, considering ES6+

Function.prototype.bind() wouldn't be ideal since I need the `this` reference to not change in my actual context.

```
function initEvents () {
  const message = processSomeString();
  myButton.addEventListener(myButtonClick);
}

function myButtonClick () {
  //Some other code
  alert(message??);
}
```

Comment: "remove the nested anonymous function to improve readability"... but when you find that the other options are *less* readable, will you still want to?

Comment: @spender Well no, but I need to know the other options first :P

Comment: For max readability, I'd probably: `myButton.addEventListener( () => callSomeMethodWith(message) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the *scope*, you'll need to pass *arguments*:

```
function myButtonClick(message) {
  //Some other code
  alert(message);
}

function initEvents() {
  const message = processSomeString();

  myButton.addEventListener(() => myButtonClick.call(this, message));
  // or:
  myButton.addEventListener(myButtonClick.bind(this, message));
}
```

Though note that I find it weird to preserve `this` here. That would only make sense if both functions are methods on the same object, in which case `.bind(this)` is a common idiom. If they are unrelated functions, passing the `this` context this way is… unexpected.

Comment: Which would you recommend? I personally dislike using .bind, but also ananonymous function just to pass arguments to another doesn't improve readability too much.

Comment: They are in fact methods of a same object, I just didnt bother to put everything in the example.

Comment: Then the only other alternative is `...addEventListener(() => this.myButtonClick(message))`. Whether you prefer that or `bind` is a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the best solution, not only taste but in some contexts it is much safer

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```js
function initEvents () {
  const message = 'any string' //processSomeString();
  
  // pass `myButton` as first argument of `.bind`
  // so that in your `myButtonClick()` you still have reference to `this`
  myButton.addEventListener('click', myButtonClick.bind(myButton, message));
}

function myButtonClick(message, e){
  console.log(`this: ${this}`);
  console.log(`message: ${message}`);
}

initEvents();
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

Please note that in your code, this line: `myButton.addEventListener(myButtonClick)` won't work because you lack one ["eventType" argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for `.addEventListener`.

**Edit to fit question:**

To preserve `this` keyword reference, simply pass `this` as first argument:

```js
function initEvents () {
  const message = 'any string' //processSomeString();

  // For JS beginners, just read the documentation link above for explanation
  myButton.addEventListener('click', myButtonClick.bind(this, message));
}

function myButtonClick(message, e){
  console.log(`this: ${this}`);
  console.log(`message: ${message}`);
}

initEvents();
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

Comment: OP wants to preserve `this` context…

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure whether I overlooked it too or it was added later…